# How to extend the rules with ability to override existing ones

Tags: drools

I need to design a solution where a set of rules can be extended with another set of rules without having to modify the original set.

Problem:
There are possible conflicts when simply combining rules from different rule sets since multiple rules can be matched. The system should trigger only the extended rule when in conflict with the base rule.

Example:

An time tracking system for determining overtime has a threshold to decide when the extra time counts for overtime.

- A base rule counts overtime as time exceeding min. 30 minutes.
- An extended rule counts overtime as time exceeding min. 60 minutes.

So extended rule is more strict because you have to work for at least
60 minutes to be counted as extra time (otherwise you get 0) but the
original rules counts anything above 30 minutes.

So it both rules as present and you spent +45 minutes at work the base
rule will fire and count it. But we don't want that because the extended rule has higher threshold.

Comment: Are your extended rules actually extending (via `extends` keyword) the base ones?

Comment: Via `extends` it would not be possible to override rules arbitrarily as you can only extend the base by adding more criteria. I am sort of looking for a clever trick to disable rules in the base from a different DRL file and add others. The assumption is that the base is released independently so I can't really change to it. A good analogy would be the inheritance in OOP languages.

Comment: Right, by using the `extends` keyword would be impossible to do what you were asking for. I was just checking that. As far as I can tell, there is no way way to do what you are looking for. One way could be to add a meta information to your rules so you build your kie-bases with just the rules you need. Another alternative would be to add an indirection layer in your rules so they don't exectue the actions themselves, but they insert an Intent that another layer of rules can then analyze and decide which Intent should be used.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti It seems that to build a hierarchy I can use modules hierarchy e.g. `<kbase name="kbase-extended-rules" packages="org.myrules.rules" includes="kbase-base-rules">`. I tested this to work. To override a conflicting rule the base rule must be inserted logically and annotated as `@Defeasible`. An overriding rule must have `@Defeats("base rule")`. I have to test that yet but that is my understanding so far from reading _Mastering JBoss Drools 6_ chapter _Logical insertion of elements_.

Answer (score 0):

You could put each rule in a different `agenda-group`. When you want to use your 30 minute rule `focus` on the `agenda-group` that contains it. When you want to use your 60 minute rule `focus` on the `agenda-group` that contains that.

Alternatively `focus` both `agenda-groups`. The rules we be matched in the most recently focused `agenda-group` first.

Comment: This solution would not fulfill the requirement: **set of rules can be extended with another set of rules without having to modify the original set**. This is needed in order to have independent releases cycles for base and extended rules. With `agenda` group I would have to put conflicting rule to the same file.

Comment: OK - have you tried using an AgendaFilter? That will let you determine whether or not the default rule should actually run.